# Adding progress bar or percentage to tune function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, progress-bar, svm

In **e1071** library of R has an inbuilt tune() function to optimize our algorithm.

```
tuneop=tune(svm,y~.,data=dat,kernel="radial",ranges=list(cost=c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1,5,10,100),gamma=c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1,5,10)))
```

I use tune function to optimize my gamma and cost parameter in my SVM model. For small dataset **tune()** requires only a small amount of time to generate **bestmodel** . But for a very large data set it takes a lot of time. So is it possible to add a progress bar or percentage to monitor the progress of the tuning of our model.

Comment: Progress bars usually used with a loops.

Comment: For very large sets SVMs may not be applicable at all. The computational costs scale approximately with N^3 if N is the number of observations.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but I use the `beep()` function from the [beepr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beepr/index.html) package. It makes a sound when a command is finished.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware e1071 doesn't include a option for a progress bar or verbose mode in it's tuning method.

However the `tune` method is a simple grid search, from the documentation

> This generic function tunes hyperparameters of statistical methods using a grid search over supplied
>   parameter ranges.

So it would be fairly simple for you to write your own tuning function.

Otherwise you could use a package which wraps e1071 and implements it's own tuning method with better verbosity, such as [mlr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html) or [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html).